# prnmngr.vbs - parse and format output as csv from a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, wsh

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('Cscript %WINDIR%\\System32\\Printing_Admin_Scripts\\en-US\\Prnmngr.vbs -l -s myserver1.com') do (
  echo %%f
)
pause
```

output looks like  :

```
Server name myserver1.com
Printer name myprinter1
Share name myprinter1
Driver name SHARP UD2 PCL6
Port name myprinter1.com
Comment
Location
Print processor winprint
Data type RAW
Parameters
Attributes 584
Priority 1
Default priority 0
Average pages per minute 0
Printer status Idle
Extended printer status Unknown
Detected error state Unknown
Extended detected error state Unknown
```

and so on for 100 printers

output expected in a csv file is the **server name**, **printer name** **share name**, **driver name**, **port name** as shown below:

```
myserver1.com,myprinter1,myprinter1,SHARP UD2 PCL6,myprinter1.com
myserver2.com,myprinter2,myprinter2,hp  PCL6,myprinter2.com
myserver3.com,myprinter3,myprinter3,hp universal PCL5,myprinter3.com
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CALL :zapvars

:: for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('Cscript %WINDIR%\\System32\\Printing_Admin_Scripts\\en-US\\Prnmngr.vbs -l -s myserver1.com') do (
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (q48077575.txt) do (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims= " %%a IN ("%%f") DO IF "%%a"=="Comment" (
  CALL :report
 ) ELSE IF "%%b"=="name" SET "%%a=%%c"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:: report - use drop-through to zap variables used
:report
ECHO %server%,%printer%,%share%,%driver%,%port%

:: clear variables used
:zapvars
FOR %%z IN (server printer share driver port) DO SET "%%z="
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q48077575.txt` containing your data for my testing, supplemented by some similar data.

Note the call to `zapvars` initially to clear the variables used.

You were already reading each line to `%%f`. Tokenise each line to %%a,%%b,%%c using spaces as delimiters then if the first token is **not** `Comment`, see whether the second is `name` and set a variable named `%%a` to the value on the remainder of the line after `name`, `%%c`.

When the first token **is** `Comment`, then output the names that have been detected and clear the variables ready for the next data block.